# Why there is a white bar in between two div, CSS issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am unsure why there is a white bar between two div (.home-page and .home-intro). Below are my codings.

For the react Home component,

```
import { Box, Button, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import "./Home.css";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home-container">
      <div className="home-page">
        <div className="skewed-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="home-intro">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="available-food"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

For its CSS,

```
.home-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)),
    url("../images/meal.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.skewed-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 200px 1519px 0 0;
  border-color: transparent #fcf4d4 transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.home-intro {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fcf4d4;
}
```

Below is the figure:

[image]

I have inspected the elements, it seems that the yellow page above the white bar is under .homo-page div while the yellow page below the white bar is under .home-intro div, the white bar is neither of this two div. Thus, I am curious why this is happening, isit due to the issue of 100vh?

I do not have any ideas on how to set the .home-page div to 100vh without obtaining the white bar

Comment: There's a very high chance you have a margin somewhere that's pushing the second element down. But without seeing a working example, this is difficult for us to narrow down.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Since this is a styling issue, you could have a small example with just the rendered HTML instead of React code.

Comment: Ya, thanks for the advice, i have shorten the code

Answer (score 2):

the white bar exist here in the div "skewed-box", and that div is betwenn the two divs that you've mentionned above :home-page and  home-intro

```
  border-color: transparent #fcf4d4 transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
```

Comment: the .skewed-box div is wrapped inside .home-page div. Also, when I inspect the element, .skewed-box div is included in the .home-page div without interfering the white bar section